# Apply filters on conditional binding expression

Tags: angularjs

How to apply currency filter on  below expression. I tried putting "| currency" after 
bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsCalculated: and     bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsOverride
but angular is throwing an error.

```
    <td>
      <div class="currencyLabel-readonly" ng-cloak>
       {{bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsOverride == 0 ? bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsCalculated: bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsOverride}}
      </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;(B)
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your expression in `()`

```
{{ (bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsOverride == 0 ? bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsCalculated: bridgeModel.bridges[currentIndex].aestheticsOverride) | currency }}
```